# SQLiteException while updating record with string comparision

Tags: android

My record: (ID, name, count)

(1, 1, 2)
(2, t, 10)

It works: myDbHelper.updateCount("1", 100);

It didn't work: myDbHelper.updateCount("t", 100); It gave android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:no such column: t: , while compiling: ...

Here is the code for updating records:

```
public int updateCount(String name, int count) {
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues(); 
    args.put(KEY_COUNT, count);
    return mDb.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_NAME + "=" + name, null);    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use Strings in WHERE clause ensure you enclose the value in Single quotes.

If your column name is "username" and value is "ABCD" & cv has the Content values, then the way to query is as follows -

```
    String updateDBString = "username=" + "'ABCD'";
    mDB.update(TABLE_NAME, cv, updateBDString, null);
```